# Can a woman who converted at a late age (25 for example) show her pictures without hair before she converted?

Tags: women, hijab, conversion

For example, a woman converted at the age of 25, would she be able to show her pictures which were taken before she converted (age of 24 for example) and with her hair showing?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, she may have to show her old photos. For example, the government ID's and driving license may have her old photo.

Chances of simply sharing her old photos should be reduced.

Answer (score -8):

Every woman in the world can show whatever she can. Your asking is very weird: why would somebody even tried to stop the woman from showing her hairs? We are not savages, we take care about our woman, about theirs rights to express themselves. I even think that woman are superior to man: they can give birth...

Comment: **<comments deleted>** @AbAppletic Comments are meant for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are not meant for debating controversial points.

Comment: I can not see a better clarification of this than saying STOP this type of behavior to woman....

Comment: @ViktorPodlipský I hate wrong behavior to woman. I absolutely hate the stupid things saying a woman should never leave her house, a woman should never talk to a man, a woman cannot use an electronic, etc. I hate those. But sir, it is found in the Quran that a woman will have a higher place in heaven if she wears Hijab